# Set time() on ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, time

If I call configTime() on a ESP8266 using ESP8266 Core, then time() gets changed from uptime to unixtime. However this sends a SNTP request. I have a DS3231 RTC attached without internet. How can I set time() without calling configTime()?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably [`settimeofday(...)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/settimeofday) is what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you have `epoch` time, either from RTC, NTP, etc., use the POSIX function settimeofday() to set system time as @Majenko said

The sample code is as follows:

```
// Assuming we already have Unix `epoch` time, which is time from Jan 1 1970.
// From RTC, NTP, etc.
time_t epoch_t = epoch;

// set the time to UTC
setTime(epoch_t);

// set the system time to UTC
timeval tv = { epoch_t, 0 };
settimeofday(&tv, nullptr);

// Now we can have system time by calling time()
time_t timeNowUTC;
struct tm * timeInfo

timeNowUTC = time(nullptr);
timeInfo = localtime(&timeNowUTC);
```

---

For the record, the issue has been solved in Arduino Forum : [**Update time() from DS3231**](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/update-time-from-ds3231/962252/5)